# How can I express this properly? Using && and || for the first time

Tags: java

I have never used && or || in my class before and I'm completely lost on how to properly use them. In my mind I was thinking something like what i had below would work, but it did not.

```
public class ScoreDice {
    // TODO - write your code below this comment.
    // You will need to write one method: scoreWithNumbers.
    // scoreWithNumbers returns a score based on the values
    // of its inputs, as such:
    //
    // - If both inputs are 1 or if both inputs are 6, then
    //   the returned score is 10
    // - If both inputs are the same (but not 1 or 6), then
    //   the returned score is 8
    // - If the inputs are different, the score is whatever the
    //   smaller value is (e.g., if given 3 and 4, it returns 3).
    //
    public static String scoreWithNumbers(int num1, int num2) {
        if ((num1==6 && num2==6) || (num2==1 && num1==1)) {
            return "10";
        } else if ((1 < num1 || num1 < 6) && num2==num1) {
            return "8";
        }
    } 

    public static int scoreWithSeed(long seed) {
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        int num1 = rollD6(random);
        int num2 = rollD6(random);
        return scoreWithNumbers(num1, num2);
    }

    public static int rollD6(Random random) {
        // random.nextInt(6) returns a number between
        // 0 and 5, inclusive.  We want to simulate rolling
        // a D6 (6-sided die) so we add one to this result.
        return random.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter seed: ");
        long seed = input.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Score: " + scoreWithSeed(seed));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ (preferably 10 lines or less) to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How did it not work? Do you mean the last requirement (return the smallest of the inputs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code with comments explaining what is happening at each step of the if statement:

Basically what I changed was I made sure you were returning int's as the TODO does not say `scoreWithNumbers` should return strings, similarly I added the code for getting two different numbers and changed the type from `long` to `int` since `int` is more appropriate for the relevant testing of `scoreWithNumbers()` part of your program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScoreDice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first input number: ");
        int firstInputInt = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second input number: ");
        int secondInputInt = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Returned score from the method scoreWithNumbers: " + scoreWithNumbers(firstInputInt, secondInputInt));
    }

    public static int scoreWithNumbers(int num1, int num2) {
        // If both inputs are 1 or if both inputs are 6, then the returned score is 10
        if ((num1==1 && num2==1) || (num1==6 && num2==6)) {
            return 10;
        // If both inputs are the same (but not 1 or 6 [we checked that above]), then the returned score is 8
        } else if (num1 == num2) {
            return 8;
        // If the inputs are different (i.e if (num1 != num2)), the score is whatever the smaller value is (e.g., if given 3 and 4, it returns 3).  
        } else {
            return Math.min(num1, num2);
        }
    } 
}
```

**Example Usage (Case 1: Both inputs are 1 or if both inputs are 6)**

```
Enter first input number:  1
Enter second input number:  1
Returned score from the method scoreWithNumbers: 10

Enter first input number:  6
Enter second input number:  6
Returned score from the method scoreWithNumbers: 10
```

**Example Usage (Case 2: Both inputs are the same but not 1 or 6)**

```
Enter first input number:  4
Enter second input number:  4
Returned score from the method scoreWithNumbers: 8
```

**Example Usage (Case 3: Both inputs are different)**

```
Enter first input number:  3
Enter second input number:  5
Returned score from the method scoreWithNumbers: 3
```

**N.B.** The final `else` can be removed and you can just have `return Math.min(num1, num2)` since that part of the code will only be reached if both the `if` and the `else if` blocks are not evaluated before hand.

Comment: "We only need to check num1 is not 1 and not 6" -- actually, you don't need to check either `num1` or `num2` at that point.  If they are equal, we _know_ that they can't be 1 or 6.

Comment: @ajb Noted my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your `scoreWithNumbers` method one part at a time:

```
public static String scoreWithNumbers(int num1, int num2) {
    if ((num1==6 && num2==6) || (num2==1 && num1==1)) {
```

This line, which is supposed to check whether both inputs are 1 or both inputs are 6, does exactly that.  Therefore you're not "completely lost".  I think you understand `&&` and `||` pretty well.

```
        return "10";
    } else if ((1 < num1 || num1 < 6) && num2==num1) {
```

Here, you want to check whether both numbers are the same (and not 1 or 6).  All the checks involved are equality or inequality checks (numbers are equal, numbers don't equal 1 and don't equal 6), so the only comparisons you should have here are `==` and `!=`.  So the problem here is your use of `>`, not `||` or `&&`.

The first part of your `if` tests whether `num1` is greater than 1 *or* less than 6.  (Of course `1 < num1` is exactly the same as `num1 > 1`.)  However, *every* number is either greater than 1 or less than 6, so this test isn't useful.

As I mentioned in a comment, if the numbers are equal, they can't be 1 or 6, because if they were, you would have returned `"10"` already.  So you don't actually need to code the "(and not 1 or 6)" part.  But if that statement weren't there, you could write it as

```
num1 != 1 && num1 != 6
```

A lot of new programmers fall into a trap that when they see a requirement that "Check that some value doesn't equal X or Y", they use `||` because there's an "or" in the requirement.  That's how we talk in English.  But in programming, the way to think about it is "value is unequal to X *and* value is unequal to Y."

```
        return "8";
    }
}
```

You should have gotten a compiler error at this point.  What happens if neither `if` is true?  You will get to the end of the method without returning anything, but you need to return something.  It looks like the last part of the requirement is missing, that you need to return the smaller of the two numbers.  You can do this with another `if` statement that compares `num1 < num2`, and based on this, either `return num1` or `return num2`.  Or you can use `Math.min`.  Except that you've said that the method returns a `String`, so you can't simply return `num1` or `num2` (or `Math.min(num1,num2)`).  You can fix this by making your method return an `int` and fixing the other `return` statements.

Answer (score 0):

This code is almost fine

```
public static String scoreWithNumbers(int num1, int num2) {
    if ((num1==6 && num2==6) || (num2==1 && num1==1)) {
        return "10";
    } else if ((1 < num1 || num1 < 6) && num2==num1) {
        return "8";
    }
    // add a return here
    // maybe
    return null; // ??
}
```

**BUT** what happens **if** the `if` and the `else if` conditions are not met - you need to return something

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is that `scoreWithNumbers()` returns just "10" or "8". **You forgot to add the code for `scoreWithNumbers()` to return the lower number when the numbers are not equal.**

But that is not what you asked. You said that you were having trouble understanding `||` and `&&`, so let's talk about that instead.

> The `||` and `&&` operator are short-circuit, meaning that they won't bother checking the right-hand (in)equality if the left-hand one is enough to know the result.

The condition `A || B` is true if `A` is true. Sure, if `A` is false and `B` is true, the condition is also true, but if `A` is already true *we don't even need to check `B`.*
Conversely, the condition `A && B` is true only when both `A` and `B` are true. That is the same as saying that the condition `A && B` is false if either `A` or `B` (or both) are false. So *if `A` is false, we don't need to check B*, we already know the condition to be false.

Now, going back to your code: careful with this: `(1 < num1 || num1 < 6)`.
**If `num1` was a `6`, `(1 < num1 || num1 < 6)` would return `true`**. Since `6` is indeed greater than `1`, the left-hand side of the comparison is true, so the result of `||` *has* to be true; the program doesn't need to check the other side of the comparison, and so it won't.
Your code works only because the values `1` and `6` are already taken care of in the first `if`, but I'm sure that is not what you want; you probably meant `(1 < num1 && num1 < 6)` which will return true when a number is both greater than 1 *and* less than 6.

So your code could be:

```
    public static int scoreWithNumbers(int num1, int num2) {
        if (num1 == num2) { // Fixed scores for equal numbers
            if (num1 == 1 || num1 == 6) { // equal 1s or 6s
                return 10;
            } else { // equal others
                return 8;
            }
        } else {
            // something something return lowest of num1, num2
        }
    }
```

I am not providing code for the "lowest" part, since your question was not about that, and this is your homework after all.